# How should look a application.scss file in ruby?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in ruby and my code looks like this: Is this correct? My boostrap does not load..

So **application.scss**

```
//= require . 
//= require_self
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery_ujs
 //= require turbolinks
 //= require bootstrap
 //= require_tree .


@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

And **application.js** looks like this:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

Thanks for any explanation!

Comment: Those `// require` lines don't belong in `application.scss`. Those are JavaScript manifest lines anyway.

Comment: Is it `*=` ? in the scss file?

Comment: Once you change `application.css` to `application.scss`, you must use Sass `@import` statements instead of the default CSS comment syntax that Rails provides in asset manifest files.

Comment: You're welcome. I know it probably doesn't solve your problem, but at least I could teach you that. :)

Comment: @ChrisPeters maybe you have a solution for this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189115/bootstrap-wont-load-with-rails-and-sass

Answer (score 0):

In sass files we does't include require,you can remove them.replace your code with as follows

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```