# Bootstrap won't load with rails and sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm new to Rails and i want to use Bootstrap on my site but Bootsrap does not load. What is wrong, what should i do diffrently?

I followed this manual: [Sass-Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass)

These are my files:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.16'
gem 'ruby'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
gem 'turbolinks'
```

**application.scss**

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**application.html.erb**

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
       <li><%= link_to "Home", welcome_index_path %></li>
       <li><%= link_to "About", welcome_about_path %></li>
  </ul>

<%= yield %>

</div>
```

My ruby Version in the project is `ruby 2.0.0p481`
My Rails Version is: `Rails 3.2.22`

Comment: So what is the problem?  Is there an error?  What is the error?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions.  If your first question does not get an answer, it's either because nobody knows, or because it lacks the information people need to help you.  If possible, improve the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap-sass is not longer compatible with rails 3,
The latest version of bootstrap-sass compatible with Rails 3.2 is v3.1.1.0.

So, change it in your gemfile to

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1.0'
```

You can read it in https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass#a-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Nope that does not do it sadly... could it be that `rails-sass` cause an error? @Nivia

Comment: did you reboot the server?

Comment: The OP is already specifying a version of bootstrap-sass that's newer than that anyway:  `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'`.